# Shell Bash Script not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

i have bash script for backup my database and i use it on other server and work fine...

Script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOME="/var/www/html"
DB="$HOME/backup/vpn-db-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S`.sql.gz"
LOG="$HOME/backup/log.txt"

echo "Backup database `date +%F` u `date +%H:%M:%S`."
echo "Backup database `date +%F` u `date +%H:%M:%S`." >> $LOG

mysqldump -u root -pmypassword mydatabase > $DB

echo "Finish at `date +%H:%M:%S`."
echo "Finish at `date +%H:%M:%S`." >> $LOG
```

Error was i get when try run from terminal is:

> ```
> root@vpn:~# sudo bash /var/www/html/backup/cron.sh
>
> /var/www/html/backup/cron.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
> /var/www/html/backup/cron.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
> Backup database 2017-04-04 u 13:51:10.
> : No such file or directory: /var/www/html
> /var/www/html/backup/cron.sh: line 9: $'\r': command not found
> : No such file or directory gz /var/www/html
> /var/www/html/backup/cron.sh: line 11: $'\r': command not found
> Finish at 13:51:10.
> : No such file or directory 3: /var/www/html
> /var/www/html/backup/cron.sh: line 14: $'\r': command not found
> ```

NOTE - Permissions of file is: **774**

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Tra  4 11:02 /var/www/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably edited the file on windoze or transferred it via windoze where one of the transfers was binary and the other text mode, thus it has trailing Carriage Returns.

Try `dos2unix /var/www/html/backup/cron.sh` to make the CRs go away.